# How to perform xUnit based Integration Test on Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I do not know how to setup `xUnit` based integration test for Azure Function. I have .NET 6.0-based Azure function `CreateObject`. I want to have one integration test for this function. The function uses the following external components:

1. Azure Redis Cache
2. Azure CosmosDb
3. Azure Service Bus
4. A REST Service for settings
5. AppSettings
6. Serilog

## CreateObject.cs

This is Azure Function.

```
public class CreateObject
{
    private readonly ICreateObjectWorkflow _workflow;

    public CreateObject(ICreateObjectWorkflow workflow)
    {
        _workflow = workflow;
    }

    [Function("CreateObject")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Body"] = await req.GetBody() 
        };

        var output = await _workflow.Run(input);

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(output);

        return response;
    }
}
```

## Startup.cs

This is a startup of Azure Function and it initializes many services.

```
namespace Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Starup;

public class Startup
{
    public Task Run()
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT")!;
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string dirPath = fileInfo.Directory!.FullName;
        var path = @$"{dirPath}/Appsettings/";

        return Run(environment, path);
    }

    public Task Run(string environment, string path)
    {
        HealthServiceConfiguration healthOptions;
        var host = new HostBuilder()
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
             {
                 builder
                     .SetBasePath(path)
                     .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                     .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                     .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.Health.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                     .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.AzureApp.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                     .AddEnvironmentVariables();

                 var config = builder.Build();
             })
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
            {
                worker.UseNewtonsoftJson();
                worker.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();

            })
            .ConfigureOpenApi()
            .UseSerilogLogging()
            .RegisterToHealthService()

            .ConfigureServices(s =>
            {
                s.AddAppSettingsOption<AppSettings>();
                s.AddAppSettingsOption<AzureIntegrationsAppSettingsConfiguration>();
                s.AddAppSettingsOption<HealthServiceConfiguration>("HealthServiceConfiguration");
                var serviceProvider = s.BuildServiceProvider();
                var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value;
                healthOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<HealthServiceConfiguration>>().Value;
                s.AddIntegrationApp($"{healthOptions.ServiceInfo.ApplicationUrl}/api");
                healthOptions.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                s.AddRedisCache(options);
                s.AddHealthCheck(options, healthOptions);
                s.AddAzureServiceBus(options.ServiceBusConnectionString);
                s.AddSignalRService();
                s.AddSingleton<INoSqlDatabase>(new CosmosNoSqlDatabase(options.CosmosDbEndpoint, options.CosmosDbPrimaryKey, options.DatabaseName));
                s.AddIntegrationAppLifeCycle();
                s.AddSerilog();
            })
            .Build();

        return host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

I tried to set up an integration test using the following classes but got an exception.

This is the exception I get when I run the integration test.

```
Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.ValidBody_ReturnCompleteNa
   Source: CreateObjectWorkflowTests.cs line 37

Test has multiple result outcomes
   2 Failed

Results

    1)   Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.ValidBody_ReturnCompleteNa(data: [[[...]], [[...]], [[...]], [[...]], [[...]], ...], result: []) 
      Duration: 1 ms

      Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : The gRPC channel URI 'http://:63530' could not be parsed.

      Stack Trace: 
<>c.<AddGrpc>b__1_1(IServiceProvider p) line 61
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
<4 more frames...>
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebFixture.InitializeAsync() line 63

       Open result log

    2)   Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.CreateObjectWorkflowTests.ValidBody_ReturnCompleteNa 
      Duration: 1 ms

      Message: 
[Test Collection Cleanup Failure (InMemory Web collection)]: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

      Stack Trace: 
WebFixture.DisposeAsync() line 70

   Open test log
```

## ICreateObjectWorkflowClient.cs

I am not sure if I have to use Refit to call an Azure function?

```
using Refit;
namespace Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.Clients;

public interface ICreateObjectWorkflowClient
{
    [Post("/api/CreateObject/")]
    Task<object> Run(Dictionary<string, object> input);
}
```

## CreateObjectWorkflowTests.cs

I am not sure if I have to use _httpClient for integration test?

```
[Collection(WebCollection.Collection)]
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public class CreateObjectWorkflowTests
{
    private readonly ICreateObjectWorkflowClient _httpClient;

    public CreateObjectWorkflowTests(WebFixture fixture)
    {
        _httpClient = RestService.For<ICreateObjectWorkflowClient>(fixture.Client, new RefitSettings
        {
            ContentSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer(
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                })
        });
    }


    [Theory]
    [JsonFileData(@".\Integration\CreateObjectWorkflowTests\Data\Customer.json", typeof(JObject), typeof(JObject))]
    public async Task ValidBody_ReturnCompleteNa(JObject data, JObject result)
    {
        // Arrange
        var entityList = data["entityList"]!;

        // Act
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Body", entityList.ToString() } };
        var output = await _httpClient.Run(input) as List<Response>;

        // Assert
        Assert.Single(output!);
        Assert.Equal("Na", output![0].Completed);
        Assert.Equal(0, output![0].Errors.Count);
        Assert.Equal(1, output![0].Ids.Count);
        Assert.Null(output![0].ResponseStatus);
        Assert.Equal(result, result);
    }
}
```

## WebCollection.cs

I am not sure if I have to use IAsyncLifetime for integration test?

```
namespace Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.Fixtures;

[CollectionDefinition(Collection)]
public class WebCollection : ICollectionFixture<WebFixture>
{
    public const string Collection = "InMemory Web collection";
}

public class WebFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    internal IHost Host;
    internal IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
    internal HttpClient Client;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var environment = "Test";
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string dirPath = fileInfo.Directory!.FullName;
        var path = @$"{dirPath}/Appsettings/";

        path = @"D:\AzureIntegrationsApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\Appsettings\";

        Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .SetBasePath(path)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.Health.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, $"appsettings.{environment}.AzureApp.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var config = builder.Build();
        })
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
        {
            worker.UseNewtonsoftJson();
            worker.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();

        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x =>
        {
            x.UseTestServer();
            x.UseStartup<Internal.Startup>();
        }).Build();

        await Host.StartAsync();
        ServiceProvider = Host.Services;
        Client = Host.GetTestClient();
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        Client.Dispose();
        await Host.StopAsync();
        Host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

## Startup.cs

I am not sure if I have to use custom Startup for integration test?

```
namespace Get.Caa.IntegrationsApp.Test.Integration.Internal
{
    internal class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection s)
        {
            s.AddAppSettingsOption<AppSettings>();
            s.AddAppSettingsOption<AzureIntegrationsAppSettingsConfiguration>();
            s.AddAppSettingsOption<HealthServiceConfiguration>("HealthServiceConfiguration");
            
            var serviceProvider = s.BuildServiceProvider();
            var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value;

            //var healthOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<HealthServiceConfiguration>>().Value;
            //s.AddIntegrationApp($"{healthOptions.ServiceInfo.ApplicationUrl}/api");
            //healthOptions.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            //s.AddHealthCheck(options, healthOptions);

            s.AddRedisCache(options);
            s.AddAzureServiceBus(options.ServiceBusConnectionString);
            s.AddSignalRService();
            s.AddSingleton<INoSqlDatabase>(new CosmosNoSqlDatabase(options.CosmosDbEndpoint, options.CosmosDbPrimaryKey, options.DatabaseName));
            s.AddIntegrationAppLifeCycle();
            s.AddSerilog();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Passing test data to a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?source=recommendations&tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#passing-test-data-to-a-function) section says, you have to start the Functions host to perform integration testing

Comment: I blogged a little while ago about an approach I've been using for a while now which may be useful: https://www.adathedev.co.uk/2022/01/e2e-testing-azure-functions.html


References a full sample app here: https://github.com/AdaTheDev/AzureFunctions-E2ETest-Example

Not familiar with Corvus.Testing.AzureFunctions - but looks very similar

Comment: @AdaTheDev Corvus testing library abstracts launch, stop and log collection in a simple fixture, so your tests are very clean and you could focus more on writing useful test logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source library [Corvus.Testing.AzureFunctions](https://github.com/corvus-dotnet/Corvus.Testing/tree/main/Solutions/Corvus.Testing.AzureFunctions) available to perform integration tests on Azure Functions. I copied the complete library in my xUnit test project and created 2 classes to launch and test Azure Function `CreateObject`. Here are those classes:

## CreateObjectFixture.cs

This class basically set up test log location and azure function location. It also launches the function host environment and stops it.

```
public class CreateObjectFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly FunctionsController function;

    public CreateObjectFixture(IMessageSink output)
    {
        ILogger logger = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddSerilog(
                new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.File(@$"C:\temp\{this.GetType().FullName}.log")
                    .WriteTo.TestOutput(output)
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .CreateLogger())
            .CreateLogger("CreateObject Tests");

        this.function = new FunctionsController(logger);
    }

    public int Port => 7071;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await this.function.StartFunctionsInstance(
            @"Get.Caa.AzureIntegrationsApp",
            this.Port,
            "net6.0");
    }

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        this.function.TeardownFunctions();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

## CreateObjectTests.cs

This class uses fixture to launch the host environment and send a POST request to the azure function `CreateObject`. I have also used [xUnitHelper](https://github.com/AnkurSheel/xUnitHelpers) library for easy JSON file handling.

```
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public class CreateObjectTests : IClassFixture<CreateObjectFixture>
{
    private readonly CreateObjectFixture _fixture;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CreateObjectTests(CreateObjectFixture fixture)
    {
        this._fixture = fixture;
        this._httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    private int Port => _fixture.Port;

    private string Uri => $"http://localhost:{this.Port}/CreateObject";

    [Theory]
    [JsonFileData(@".\Integration\CreateObjectTests\Data\Customer.json", typeof(JObject), typeof(JObject))]
    public async Task ValidBody_ReturnCompleteNa(JObject data, JObject result)
    {
        // Arrange
        var entityList = data["entityList"]!;
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Body", entityList.ToString() } };
        var requestBody = new StringContent(
                JObject.FromObject(input).ToString(Formatting.None),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");
        // Act
        var output = await this._httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, requestBody).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(output);
    }
}
```